# How long does it take a patent application to appear in the USPTO database?

Tags: uspto, search, databases

I have several patents that I have filed which have been received by the USPTO, but have yet to appear when I search the USPTO online database.

How long is the delay between filing and appearance on the USPTO site?
Will I be notified when the applications appear there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [USPTO FAQ](http://www.uspto.gov/faq/patents.jsp):

> Most patent applications filed on or after November 29, 2000, will be
>   published **18 months after the filing date** of the application, or any
>   earlier filing date relied upon under Title 35, United States Code.
>   Otherwise, all patent applications are maintained in the strictest
>   confidence until the patent is issued or the application is published.

*Emphasis mine*

(This was in response to the question, *Is there any danger that the USPTO will give others information contained in my application while it is pending?*)

Title 35 [in the USC](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/35/122) (which the above FAQ cites) has this to say:

> Subject to paragraph (2), each application for a patent shall be
>   published, in accordance with procedures determined by the Director,
>   promptly after the expiration of a period of 18 months from the
>   earliest filing date for which a benefit is sought under this title.
>   At the request of the applicant, an application may be published
>   earlier than the end of such 18-month period.

**Bottom line:** 18 months after you file it, unless you request that it's published sooner.

There are some exceptions that provide that the application isn't published, but I don't think they are really important to your question (read: they were too dry for me to get through).